# Viewing an image using the activity manager

Tags: android, automation

I'm writing an automation script to check my new photo gallery application. I've been trying to get am to show images using the ACTION_VIEW intent but for some reason it doesn't work. Here's what I've tried:

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "file:///sdcard/Android/test.jpg"
```

or

```
adb shell am start "file:///sdcard/Android/test.jpg"
```

however, both commands fail with the following error:

> Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=/sdcard/Android/test.jpg }
>   Error: Activity not started, unable to resolve Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=/sdcard/Android/test.jpg flg=0x10000000 }

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a MIME type on that `Intent` via the -`t` switch. See this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3228245/how-can-i-deliver-parameters-to-a-test-function-that-launched-using-adb-shell-am) and answer for more details.