# Android openApp tag

Tags: android, browser

Kind of new to scripting...
An app, my_app, is installed on the device. I need a script command to open that app and pass arguments. Something like iPhone's openApp tag.

Also How do I pass arguments to my_app.

10xs,
Nir

Answer (score 0):

In order to receive arguments, your app has to be set up to extract arguments from the Intent that launches it.  All android apps are built around Intents and Intent processing as opposed to script launching and execution.  [Look into intents](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) for more information about them if you need it, but essentially when your app is set up, presuming your script is running from your desktop, the command to start would be

```
adb am start org.example.myapp.MyActivity -e arg1 foo;
```

A quick search shows [another SO answer that explains all the arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3228245/how-can-i-deliver-parameters-to-a-test-function-that-launched-using-adb-shell-a) of am and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233873/how-to-get-extra-data-from-intent-in-android) showing how to extract extras from an intent.

Comment: 10xs. My question is not about extracting the args but rather how to pass the, I'm looking for how should the link look like.

Comment: So you mean script as in Javascript? from a webpage?

Comment: if so then you need this, I think: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469908/make-a-link-in-the-android-browser-start-up-my-app