# How to start android activity from eclipse with custom Intent

Tags: android, eclipse, android-intent, adb

I would like, for multiple testing purposes, start my android activity from Eclipse with specific data on the intent (e.g. extra data like a file name to load).
Where in the menus can I provide this?

- In the run configuration, there are nothing in the 3 tabs to provide any arguments
- I could change some parameters in the resources files but I am afraid I might leak resources which will go to the final application.
- It is possible to do it in adb: [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3229077/1287856) but it is not currently associatable with the F11 launch command in Eclipse that is useful for recompiling and relaunching at the same time.

Comment: Could you give more details about what you wanna?

Comment: I guess there are no visual support (wizard) to do it. I looked for it now too but I can't find out.

Comment: I just want to press F11 and see my application launched with special data in the intent. Because I am sharing this project with others people, I do not want to add this data directly in the project itself.

Comment: Understood so I figure out that is no way by some wizard of Eclipse. You could simulate it internally in your `Activity` where you getting `Intent` by `getIntent()` and extras by `getExtras()`.

Comment: Also the answer of @Aegis is the best for now.

Comment: For now... 23h left if someone finds a better solution or more detailed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your still using eclipse you probably need need to create a simple ant script with a custom task to execute the test. ADB shell has a command to start activities where you can also specify extra's

```
am [start|instrument]

am start [-a <action>] [-d <data_uri>]
[-t <mime_type>] [-c <category> [-c <category>] ...]
[-e <extra_key> <extra_value>
[-e <extra_key> <extra_value> ...]
[-n <component>] [-D] [<uri>]

am instrument [-e <arg_name> <arg_value>] [-p <prof_file>] [-w] <component>
```

You would pass them like this:

```
am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -c android.intent.category.DEFAULT -e foo bar -e bert ernie -n org.package.name/.MyCustomActivity
```

P.S. don't forget the dot before the activity.

This can be translated to an ant target which you should put in the ant script.

```
<target name="run">
    <exec executable="adb">
        <arg value="shell"/>
        <arg value="am"/>
        <arg value="start"/>
        <arg value="-a"/>
        <arg value="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <arg value="-e"/>
        <arg value="extra_key extra_value"/>
        <arg value="-n"/>
        <arg value="{package.name}/{activity}"/>
    </exec>
</target>
```

which you can execute like this: `ant debug install run`

How to run ant files from eclipse see:

- [Eclipse Help ant](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2FgettingStarted%2Fqs-84_run_ant.htm)
- [Eclipse Help Application launcher](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.pde.doc.user%2Fguide%2Ftools%2Flaunchers%2Feclipse_application_launcher.htm)

Comment: Please add information on how to run this script from Eclipse.

Comment: I edited the answer. to include links to the eclipse help pages

Comment: Thank you. Does it work regularly with the debugger ? What is the name the ant file should have?

Comment: build.xml I think in the root of your project folder. debugging should always work with the debugger as long as the device is in developer mode and apk is debuggable.