# Start Android activity from command line with extra

Tags: android, android-intent, adb

I created a simple activity that I want to start from command line and pass in some value from command line.

However, if I try to do

```
adb shell am start com.example.mike.app/.SimpleActivity --es "Message" "hello!"
```

and then receive the message in activity, `intent.getExtras()` returns null.

Activity:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.simple_activity);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    Log.d(LOGTAG, intent == null ? "Intent is null" : "Intent is not null");
    Log.d(LOGTAG, bundle == null ? "Bundle is null" : "Bundle is not null");
}
```

Result:

```
SimpleActivity(12345): Intent is not null
SimpleActivity(12345): Bundle is null
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3228245/how-can-i-deliver-parameters-to-a-test-function-that-launched-using-adb-shell-a/3229077#3229077

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The right command should be

```
adb shell am start -n com.example.mike.app/.SimpleActivity --es "Message" "hello!"
```

with `-n`....

Comment: How can we pass then extra of type long?

Comment: @UbaierBhat    [--el <EXTRA_KEY> <EXTRA_LONG_VALUE> ...]

Comment: There is the [docs of am start](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb#IntentSpec). Or, `adb shell am help start` to view the full args list.