# how to play video on vlc in a loop via adb shell

Tags: android, adb, vlc

I'm trying to play a video on android via adb shell on vlc **several times** in a row.
When playing the video **once** the following command was sufficient:

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW  -d  file:////storage/emulated/0/Download/bbb_sunflower_native_60fps_normal.mp4
```

But now I want to play the video several times/infinitely. Based on: [How can I deliver parameters to a test function, that launched using adb shell am Instrumentation command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3228245/how-can-i-deliver-parameters-to-a-test-function-that-launched-using-adb-shell-a][1]) , [Start Android activity from command line with extra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33704227/start-android-activity-from-command-line-with-extra?noredirect=1&lq=1][2]) and https://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_command-line_help/ I tried:

```
adb shell am start -n org.videolan.vlc/org.videolan.vlc.gui.video.VideoPlayerActivity -e input-repeat 3 -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d file:////storage/emulated/0/Download/bbb_sunflower_native_60fps_normal.mp4
```

with various combinations including passing `--input-repeat 3` and `"input-repeat" 3` without success. E.g: **the video would play but only once**.

Also didn't help:

```
adb shell am start -n org.videolan.vlc/org.videolan.vlc.gui.video.VideoPlayerActivity -e PlaybackMode 1 -d  file:////storage/emulated/0/Download/bbb_sunflower_native_60fps_normal.mp4
```

Does anyone know how it can be done?

Comment: try to make android app with LibVLC, so you can have VLC based player. using putExtra on start you can read passed param.

Answer (score 0):

Create playlist, place "bbb_sunflower_native_60fps_normal.mp4" twice or more inside and loop it by VLC

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).