# Is it possible to make debug commands in Android?

Tags: android, debugging, android-logcat

I Android you can log things with:

`Log.i("Log_Tag","Message");`

I know this prints message to the logcat console.

I also noticed it is possible to type into the logcat console.

So I was wondering is there a way to program "debugging" commands so that if you type something in the logcat console it will run a method in your program.

Comment: Use intents from adb to set runtime parameters. See: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3228245/295004

Comment: Any reason from the downvoter?

Answer (score 0):

I don´t think that this is possible.
You can add breakpoints and run your project in debug. When you stop on a breakpoint you can view your variables or use the calculator symbol (Evaluate Expression - alt + F8) to run a method or something else.